# What should we do if a question has an answer on some other SE?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

So there is [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141650/how-to-enable-only-tls-1-2-in-java-blocking-ssl-tls1-0-and-tls-1-1) which already has an answer on StackOverflow.
I can't mark it as a duplicate because the other question is not on information security SE. At the same time, I don't see a point migrating as well because it will be marked as a duplicate over there. What should we do in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mod flag can work in this scenario. The mods can sort out to migrate or close it down.

There are limitations in what can be done if the question already has an accepted answer or answers with a lot of points.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is on topic on both sites (and that is a big if) I would say that you don't need to do anything. I don't think cross site duplicates are inherently bad - for instance [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) highly upvoted question started as a deliberate duplicate of a quesiton on Server Fault.

You can leave a helpful link to the cross site duplicates in the comments (as I see you did), but apart from that I would say that no action is warranted.